# How to add annotations to Spock block?

Tags: groovy, annotations, spock

I am trying to create an annotation which can be added to Groovy classes, spock features and spock blocks. The annotation before the 'when' block fails as it is not recognized by the spock language parser. Does anyone know a solution for my problem?

```
@MyAnnotation("Info")
class MySpec extends Specification {

  @MyAnnotation("Info")
  def setupSpec () {
    //...
  }

  @MyAnnotation("Info")
  def "test feature X"() {  

    @MyAnnotation("Info")
    when:
      //...
    then:
      //...
  } 
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Cheers,
Dennis

Comment: aren't there supposed to be `@`s?

Comment: yes forgot them in my example - edited it, thanks

Comment: Java (and Groovy) annotations have a `Target` associated with them which dictates where the annotation can be applied.  For example, if an annotation has a `Target` of `ElementType.METHOD` that means that the annotation can only be applied to a method, not a class declaration or a field or a local variable or anything else.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Target.html.  I don't know what you are hoping will happen if you put your `MyAnnotation` annotation in the middle of a test method, but you can't do that.

Comment: If you remove the `Target` from your annotation it can be applied to every element type (just not in context of spock apparently). Some annotations are known to be attached to basic elements such as variable declarations (`@SuppressWarnings`). Our main purpose is to use the annotation as a marker which follows a convention and has more weight than a comment to someone reading the spec.

Comment: Annotations in general can only be applied to declarations. They cannot be applied to non-declaration statements or expressions. That is why you cannot annotate your `when` clause.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you can't.

The `when`, `then`, `expect`, `where`, etc are basically [`labels`](http://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#_labeled_statements).